# Deploy WCF Service to IIS when it only has an App.config

Tags: c#, wcf

I've add a project type of WCF Service Library to my project.  Doing this has allowed me to develop and test a WCF Service, however this service runs off an App.config and not Web.config.  In addition, it has no .SVC file like my prior projects.  What do I need to do in order to deploy this to IIS 6.

Regards.

Comment: why not deploying as a Web Service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically four steps:

1. take the `<system.serviceModel>` part from your app.config and put it in web.config
2. Add a virtual directory to IIS6
3. Add the service library's DLL to the ".\bin" directory under that virtual directory
4. Add an `MyService.svc` file to that directory which contains :

That's about all there is to it!

Marc

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Visual Studio 2008 SP1, there is actually a publish feature from the WCF Service Library template which you can use to publish to IIS.  It's available through the Build menu, or from the context menu when you right-mouse-click on the project from Solution Explorer.