# Changing Web Service from Localhost to Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services, deployment

I've got a small WCF service I've created.

I can edit it and get it working great on the localhost, but my PC is not where this application is going to be run from. It is going to run on our Server.

However, every time I try making any kind of change to the project that points it to our server, the entire project goes to crap: I can no longer view the project in a browser and my test console application can not connect to it. I try changing it back to using the local IIS web server, but then the local machine does not start up IIS whenever the project is started so it doesn't work either.

I can debug and troubleshoot for a day or so to get it working again on the local machine, but then I'm back to Square 1 where I need to deploy my application onto our Server.

This is freakin' maddening!

My project works, but I can't seem to get it from Localhost to a real Server.

All the examples I find online show how to do this using Localhost. Does no one ever deploy their projects?

Where is the Guide for getting me from Development stage to Deploy?

[image: screenshot]

[image: error]

Comment: have you tried using svcutil? http://www.nitrix-reloaded.com/2011/02/22/generating-wcfwebservice-proxy-class-using-svcutil-exe/ using that u can keep the service urls in a config file. and resuable too

Comment: Never heard of it. Could you give me more info? In the link, the author says it was to maintain proxy stubs. We used to have our Internet on a proxy, but we don't anymore. Is this the same thing? Does this file run on my machine only or on the server as well?

Comment: more here too .. http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/193466-Deploy-Wcf-service-IIS.aspx ..point 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some nice tutorials here

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/193466-Deploy-Wcf-service-IIS.aspx

http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-IIS-Hosting.aspx

also on SO [Deploy WCF Service to IIS when it only has an App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246849/deploy-wcf-service-to-iis-when-it-only-has-an-app-config)

Also a video on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX8quq7MoeI

Comment: Well, after spending a few hours on the links and the links those links referenced to and making changes here and there, it appears I am now able to build and test on the localhost again. I'm still not sure how to ensure whatever I deploy will work on the server, though.

Comment: There was some sort of server authentication that was in the `web.config` or `app.config` that I was able to delete to make work. Now, I am running again on **localhost**, but I still don't really know how to make my project so that I can test on **localhost** then just deploy straight to the **server** without going into the Project's Web Settings (screenshot in original question) and changing the Configuration to use the Web Server.

Comment: what i do is add the sln directory to my IIS as web application , so i dont have to publish always.. and test it from browser directly. then in my client i keep url as localhost/service.svc etc..